# I want to record screen and record video from front camera simultaneously . Is it possible?

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I want to record screen and record video from front camera simultaneously . Is it possible. I tried It gives exception of Media release . only one works either of two

```
public void setupRecorder(int resultCode, Intent data)  {


    NativeAppRecordingService.dataIntentScreenCapture = data;
    NativeAppRecordingService.resultCodeDataScreenCapture = resultCode;

    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.reset();
    recordingInfo = getRecordingInfo();
    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setVideoSource(SURFACE);

    // Enable Audio recording.......

    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setOutputFormat(MPEG_4);
    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setVideoSize(recordingInfo.width, recordingInfo.height);
    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(15 * 1000 * 100);/**change this for video quality */
    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setVideoFrameRate(recordingInfo.frameRate);
    //String outputVideoFileName = fileFormat.format(new Date());

    NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setOutputFile(Utils.getOutputVideoFileNameForAmazonS3Bucket(""));

    // NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.setOutputFile(NativeAppRecordingService.video_file.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.prepare();

        NativeAppRecordingService.projection = NativeAppRecordingService.manager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
        Surface surface = NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.getSurface();
        if (surface == null) {

            Toast.makeText(StartRecorderActivity.this, "Your device is not able to capture screen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File f = new File(Utils.getOutputVideoFileNameForAmazonS3Bucket(""));
            if (f.exists()) {
                f.delete();
            }

            // TODO if decive is not able to capture audio and video
            // todo cancel the test
            TerminatingTest();

        } else {

            NativeAppRecordingService.display = NativeAppRecordingService.projection.createVirtualDisplay(NativeAppRecordingService.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    recordingInfo.width, recordingInfo.height,
                    recordingInfo.density, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION,
                    surface, null, null);

            NativeAppRecordingService.recorder.start();

            // todo PauseRecording
            NativeAppRecordingService.isRecording = true;

            finish();
        }


    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        Toast.makeText(StartRecorderActivity.this, "Your device is not able to capture screen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File f = new File(Utils.getOutputVideoFileNameForAmazonS3Bucket(""));
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }

        // TODO if decive is not able to capture audio and video
        // todo cancel the test
        TerminatingTest();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        Toast.makeText(StartRecorderActivity.this, "Your device is not able to capture screen!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        File f = new File(Utils.getOutputVideoFileNameForAmazonS3Bucket(""));
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }

        // TODO if decive is not able to capture audio and video
        // todo cancel the test
        TerminatingTest();

    }
}
```

the above is for screen recording and the below one is for video recording

```
public static void setUpVideoRecorder() {
try {
    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
      mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
    /**
     * create video output file
     */
    video_file = getOutputMediaFile();
    /**
     * set output file in media recorder
     */
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(video_file.getAbsolutePath());
    mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(300000);
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);

    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(profile.audioBitRate);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(profile.audioSampleRate);

   /* int rotation = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    switch (mSensorOrientation) {
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_DEFAULT_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(DEFAULT_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
        case SENSOR_ORIENTATION_INVERSE_DEGREES:
            mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(INVERSE_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
            break;
    }*/
    mMediaRecorder.prepare();
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
    Log.e(TAG,"setUpVideoRecorder ioe "+ioe);
}
}
```

Here is the LogCat

```
2019-11-05 14:46:52.581 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -38
2019-11-05 14:46:52.581 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
2019-11-05 14:46:52.581 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.581 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at com.seattleapplab.trymyui.Activity.StartRecorderActivity.setupRecorder(StartRecorderActivity.java:229)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at com.seattleapplab.trymyui.Activity.StartRecorderActivity.onActivityResult(StartRecorderActivity.java:757)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4354)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4403)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1809)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
2019-11-05 14:46:52.582 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have done (in terms of code) and what error you have (stacktrace, logcat, etc.) ?

Comment: How can i post long comments its not allowing me to put code after some characters limits increase @arthur Attout

Comment: or i can post image

Comment: I have posted code image in question

Comment: Please avoid posting code in images, as some users (including myself) may not be able to view it. Prefer posting text code. If the editor complains you have too much code, it might be because you're including a lot of unnecessary code, and you should review that.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks @Arthur. I have edited the above question please refer it. And thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You still didn't include what error you have.

Comment: MediaRecorder: start failed: -38   java.lang.IllegalStateException on start method of media recorder

Comment: Please include an excerpt of the LogCat (containing this error) in your original question.

Comment: start failed: -38
2019-11-05 14:46:52.581 11771-11771/com.seattleapplab.trymyui.beta W/System.err:  java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
at com.seattleapplab.trymyui.Activity.StartRecorderActivity.setupRecorder(StartRecorderActivity.java:229)
at com.seattleapplab.trymyui.Activity.StartRecorderActivity.onActivityResult(StartRecorderActivity.java:757)